# Why does spring rest docs use MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restdocs

I'm [looking at the documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-parameters), and all the examples use

```
MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup
```

I tried these examples with

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup
```

and it seems to work.  I feel like the latter is preferable if you can get away with it.  Does this somehow degrade the functionality of spring rest docs?  Why wouldn't I want to do the latter every time?  Why doesn't the documentation use the latter?

Comment: I don't understand your concern. If you only have a controller(s), fine, use `standaloneSetup`. If you have a full context to setup, use `webAppContextSetup`. Does that documentation specify either scenario?

Comment: When would I *need* a full context to setup?

Comment: When you want beans autowired, when you have special interceptors, message converters, and other components registered for routing and processing.

Comment: @Pillar ok so that's the functionality I would be missing in my documentation?  I'm having trouble imagining how those would change the API except they could cause/prevent errors I'd see in the real api.

Comment: The [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/MockMvcBuilders.html) is probably better suited to explain the purpose of these two. But, yes, `webAppContextSetup` is intended more for a full (almost, minus the servlet container) integration test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I chose to use `webAppContextSetup` in the documentation as I wanted to encourage people to document their API using the complete implementation of the service. If you use `standaloneSetup` pieces may be missing or mocked out. It's possible that those differences will lead to inaccuracies in the documentation.

That said, you don't have to use `webAppContextSetup`. As you have observed, Spring REST Docs will work with `standaloneSetup` too. If you are confident that the environment that you create using `standaloneSetup` produces the same behaviour as `webAppContextSetup`, then it can be a good choice as it'll reduce your tests' execution time.

Comment: In our case, the effort of using `webAppContextSetup` is so much greater that we didn't want to pursue it while spiking on spring restdoc.  Thanks for the info.